# Prompt for and receive a date "MM/DD/YYYY" using CIN, ignoring the "/" characters? (in C++)

Tags: c++, date, input

Yes, this is for an assignment. I do not mind working to get an answer and I do not want the exact answer! :) This is my first C++ class. I've come into this class with prior knowledge of VBA, MySql, CSS, and HTML.

We are required to write a program with several different functions. One of them is required to receive the date input in a *`"MM/DD/YYYY"`* format.
While that in of itself is easy enough; as a beginner I would just put

```
cin >> month >> day >> year;
```

And insert the "/" afterwards when displaying back to the user.

However, I believe our professor would like the user to input the date by exactly typing "12/5/2013", or any other date.

Per his instructions:

> *The `'/'` can be read by cin. So read the `'/'` character and ignore it. Set day to equal the 3rd input, month to the first input, and year to the fifth input. Discard the 2nd and 4th input.*

^ That is where I am thrown off course.

So far we have only experienced cin when the user hits enter after each input. So I don't know if he wants the user to hit enter after 12, then again after '/', then after 5, after '/', and lastly after '2013' (using the prior example of 12/5/2013 for December 5th, 2013).

Does anyone more experienced have any possible insight as to what I should be doing? 
We have only been taught how to use "cin" to receive inputs (so we know no other methods for receiving input), and I have no idea how to go about "ignoring a character" when entered as a string such as '12/5/2013' exactly.

I would greatly appreciate any help with this!

edit: I have looked for answers on here but all of the ones that I have come across are beyond the scope of what we have been taught and are therefore not allowed in the assignment.
While I can go about understanding the logic of more advance coding easily enough, I am frustrated at my lack of ability to solve these simpler problems with any amount of ease. Hence my posting on here. I have spent several hours scanning our textbook for possible answers or clues to 'ignoring' characters in an input string but have come up short.

Comment: I would love to do that but we have not be taught that as of yet, and unfortunately, it is not allowed.:(

(Although admittedly, this is forcing me to approach things in a different manner. I am sure the solution our prof is seeking is actually quite simple. As I tend to overthink things I think this is a good exercise either way.)

Comment: Also, thank you Filip for editing my post to better display the info. Looks much better now. :)

Comment: Just add a temporary character and parse it. Then do some error checking to see if the character passed in is the proper separator (i.e. `/`). The rest should be relatively simple from there. [Spoiler](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb7543c4ea3ed83e)

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually unsure what you mean by temporary character and parse it? We must input something exactly like "12/5/2013" and then press enter. I see that your CIN is accept the three inputs for MM, DD, and YYYY separately. However, we must somehow get the date as one chunk of input and separate the mm, dd, and yyyy. Ignoring the "/" somehow. We haven't even touched on strings in class yet, which I find odd.

Comment: @Katlyn The getline is a member function of istream class and i think stream classes has finished for more see the link in my ans

Comment: Hm would there be a way to make it so that whenever the user inputs "/" it acts as if the user is pressing the enter key? That way you could write " cin >> mm >> dd >> yyyy " so that if the user types "12/25/2014" the / will force 12 as MM, 25 as DD, and then after the 2014 the user would properly hit enter. This is a pretty odd question, in all likelihood. ><

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy! The thing is: you can input more than just one thing. That means, if you write `int d; std::cin >> d;`, it's perfectly fine to input `30/06/2014`. The value of `d` becomes `30` and the rest of the input is not yet read. If you write the next `std::cin` statement, the content that is available is `/06/2014`.

You then need to consume the `/`, read the month, consume again and finally read the year.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int d;
   int m;
   int y;
   std::cin >> d; // read the day
   if ( std::cin.get() != '/' ) // make sure there is a slash between DD and MM
   {
      std::cout << "expected /\n";
      return 1;
   }
   std::cin >> m; // read the month
   if ( std::cin.get() != '/' ) // make sure there is a slash between MM and YYYY
   {
      std::cout << "expected /\n";
      return 1;
   }
   std::cin >> y; // read the year
   std::cout << "input date: " << d << "/" << m << "/" << y << "\n";
}
```

If you have the guarantee that the input format will be correct, it's OK to just write

```
std::cin >> d;
std::cin.get();
std::cin >> m;
std::cin.get();
std::cin >> y;
```

Alternatively, If you're not comfortable with using `std::cin.get()`, it's just as good as reading a character:

```
char slash_dummy;
int d;
int m;
int y;
std::cin >> d >> slash_dummy >> m >> slash_dummy >> y;
```

Here are some demos:

- [code with error checks](http://ideone.com/TXuz4U)
- [ignoring errors](http://ideone.com/urL6O2)
- [without `std::cin.get()`](http://ideone.com/hZZOvm)

Comment: okay, looks like i don't understand cin that well yet :). On a related note, it's an assignment so you should be guiding not writing the solution I think.

Comment: Hey but you'r totally wrong . you are using cin three times.

Comment: Oh my. I don't know what cerr is. Is that equivalent to cout? 
Also we are including "#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;" at the top of all of our programs so would I need to just remove any "std::" in this program ^? 

We are not required to write any errors in this program if the date is input in an incorrect format. So we must always assume it is exactly entered as "12/5/2013" or "6/20/2001". 

In this case would I write it as "cin >> d;", "cin.get() != '/'" ? 
I guess, what I am asking, is does "cin.get() != '/')" Only get any values entered by the user until '/'?

Comment: @ali786 Yes, that's the point! I'm reading three integers and am consuming the `/` characters.

Comment: @Katlyn Yes, `std::cerr` is practically the same as `std::cout`, replace that if you like. You can also remove all `std::` once you write `using namespace std;` of course.

Comment: We are only allowed to enter the date once as one input.

I am finding this task much more tedious than it really should be! Especially since we've only been in the class for a month! Oh man. 

We haven't gone over cin.get yet but I really am starting to think that we must be required to use some coding that we haven't learned yet...else we are unable to actually write something that can properly compile.

Comment: check my solution again... maybe it would solve your problem without using anything you haven't learned

Comment: @Katlyn Don't worry, it's not that difficult! I've added a version without `std::cin.get()`.

Comment: Oh my gosh, Stefan. Thank you! haha. 
I guess I couldn't wrap my head around the 3rd quote box of yours (not using the cin.get) by myself. 
Does C++ then receive ANY integer value for d until any non-integer is entered? Is that how it can correctly populate a single or double character for the variable d? Prior to this I was thinking that C++ would only recognize 1 number for each int variable? 

This is so simple omg thank you :")

Comment: @Katlyn `std::cin >> d` will fail if you provide for example "hello". But on the other hand, `cin` will not read beyond the last digit.

Comment: I would vote you up but I lack the required amount of reputation. Haha.

Both of the solutions actually worked.
I will need to research why cin.get(); works the way it does because I have no clue as of now how it's doing what it is doing.

Comment: @Katlyn If you are 100% satisfied by an answer, there is a check mark next to it and you can show your appreciation with that ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Great, I have just done so. Thank you! 
+rep in spirit.

Answer (score 0):

follow this pseudo code:

```
declare a char pointer to accept input
declare int to use as day, month and year
initialize day, month and year to 0
declare a int count to know what number you are up to

read `cin` operation into your input
increment through the input, stop if the current input position is NULL
    read out character
    if character != "/"
        if count == 0
            if month == 0
                month = (int)character
            else
                month = month * 10 + (int)character
            endif
        else 
        if count == 1
            if day == 0
                day = (int)character
            else 
                day = day * 10 + (int)character 
            endif
        else
            if year < 1000
                year = year * 10 + (int)character
            endif
        endif
        endif
    else count += 1 endif
```

and voilà you have your day, month and year from input.

Comment: Ugh I am so not used to holding shift+enter to do new lines in this comment box.

We have not touched upon arrays yet and cannot use this.

I also do not understand what you mean by discard "/"? I know we must discard it but that is something I would have no clue how to actually do in the C++ language. :( 

I apologize for not knowing more. I really am quite a beginner and I've tried for several hours to look all of this up on google and other resources...to no avail, unfortunately!

Comment: by discarding i mean if you find the "/" character, just do nothing with it and proceed. However, if you haven't learnt array then i think you have a bit of an issue right there. Have you ever seen something like this: `char input[5]` or similar?

Comment: I found a different way, see updated solution in a few seconds

Comment: appreciate to know why the negative vote, is my code wrong anywhere?

Comment: I feel really dumb right now, but I have absolutely no idea what you mean by "read `cin` operation into your input array"? Haha, sorry! D:

I think I can kind of understand what you are saying though? Is it to loop through the char of "12/5/2013" entered by the user, then stopping when it sees "/", assigning the previous to an int variable, and the continuing until the next "/" (repeating)?

Comment: when you see the "/" you increase the count so you know what number you are dealing with. Before the "/" you are working with `month`, after the first "/" you are working with `day`, and for the last case you are now dealing with `year`.

Comment: @pipja I think the pseudo code you provided isn't really wrong, but overly complicated and needs things you really shouldn't use as a beginner. pointers are a dangerous thing, character arrays just as well. Another thing: Character values won't be digits: http://ideone.com/zIzhmV `'1'` is actually the integer value `49`, so you would need to do additional calculations, not just `month = month * 10 + character`. The correct C++ code would be `month = month * 10 + (character - '0');, but again: it's just too complicated.

Comment: @stefan it is so complicated because there are too many assumptions, but i agree with you. Cheers.

Comment: @pipja also wanted to let you know I did not down vote you. I can't up or down vote as of yet. And I am just extremely appreciative of all the advice given by everyone.:) It is very humbling just how helpful everyone on here is and realizing just how little I know haha! I have a long way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use stringstreams?

```
string input;
int year, month, day;
cin >> input; // input can be 2005:03:09 or 2005/04/02 or whatever
stringstream ss(input);
char ch;
ss >> year >> ch >> month >> ch >> day;
```