# How to take input on same line in c++?

Tags: c++

> > i want to input Date in this format 2/11/2015. how can i do this using
> >     C++ ? Thanks The following method isn't working.

```
cin>>day >>month >>year ;
```

> and also user don't have to press enter .
>
> my Code is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
private :
    int day,month,year;
    char slash;
public :
    void inputdate(void)
    {
        cout<<"Enter Date in Formate (day/month/year)"<<endl;
        cin >> day >> slash >> month >> slash >> year;
    }
    void checkdate(void)
    {
        if (day<=0 || day>=32)
        {
            cout<<"Day is Wrong ! "<<endl;
        }
        if (month==2 && day>=29)
        {
            cout<<"February can have max 28 days !"<<endl;
        }
        if (month<=0 || month>=13)
        {
            cout<<"Month is wrong !"<<endl;
        }
        if (year<=1799 || year>=3000)
        {
            cout<<"Year is Wrong !"<<endl;
        }
        if ((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11)&&(day>30))
        {
            cout<<"Day is wrong ! September ,April ,June and November can have maximum 30 days ."<<endl;
        }
    }
    void showdate(void)
    {
        checkdate();
        cout<<"Date is : "<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: try scanf https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272895(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: i'm not understanding this .

Comment: `scanf("%d/%d/%d", &day, &month, &year)` or do what @SteJ suggests

Comment: You need to use scanf; cin will always wait for enter to be pressed. More details here: [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Prompt for and receive a date “MM/DD/YYYY” using CIN, ignoring the “/” characters? (in C++)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483655/prompt-for-and-receive-a-date-mm-dd-yyyy-using-cin-ignoring-the-character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dummy `char` variable to read past the `/` separator:

```
int day, month, year;
char slash; // dummy to skip past the '/'

cin >> day >> slash >> month >> slash >> year;
```

Comment: but ..have to press Enter and input is not on same line !

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS You only have to press Enter once at the end of the input. Then all the input stays on the same line.

Comment: NO....i think you better check this again....User have to press enter after each Input !

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS Not on my system or any system I have used. Perhaps it is something else that is causing your problem?  Can you provide a whole piece of code in your question that is not working for you?

Comment: oh...sorry its working well ....but the problem is if the user presses Enter nothing happens !

Comment: @RAOHAMMAS Yes. But that's a different question how to deal with the user typing in the wrong thing.

Answer (score 1):

C++ does not inherently understand text dates; you will need to either use a library which provides this functionality, or create a function yourself to convert between the text format and the internal integer format (which is generally the number of seconds or milliseconds, depending on platform, since the "Epoch" (00:00 1st January 1970)).

To do this you will need to:

- Collect the date as a single string or character array
- Separate the date into its constituent day/month/year
- Calculate this date as a number of seconds since the Epoch

Having said all this, the first option of using a Library is probably best as it will also contain functions to switch between string and internal date format; which library you choose is up to you and will largely depend on the platform you're coding for.

Comment: i dont know what you are trying to say !

Comment: You can't just use `cin << var1 << var2 << var3;` and expect the compiler to know that you're dealing with a date and that each value is separated by a '/'. You will need to read the entire date as a single variable (eg `cin << mydate;`) and then process that string to turn it into data you can use in your program.

Comment: you mean that ..take Date input as a string !

Comment: Yes, take date input as a *single* string and then code to split that string into your required day, month and year. You may need to bear in mind that date formats differ in different parts of the world; we (in the UK) write it as DD/MM/YYYY whereas the USA use MM/DD/YYYY and the internationally accepted (ISO) format is YYYY-MM-DD. I was assuming you need Day, Month and Year as integers rather than characters, in which case you will have further conversions to do too. Hope this helps!

Comment: but then how can i apply checks on date ?

Comment: For that you're best off using a library, otherwise you're going to have to code your own function to take into account leap years, leap seconds and so forth. Take a look [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_date_time.htm) for a starting point