# How to read in values in C++ without a space?

Tags: c++

I want to read in the user input "1/1/2010" into the corresponding int month day and year variables. However, if I do something like

cin >> month >> day >> year;

It does not work because of the slashes. Is there a way to read this user input into the variables while excluding the slashes?

Comment: You can use getLine + strtok()   with '/' as a delimiter, then read in values accordingly.

Comment: `char del; int month, day, year; cin >> month >> del >> day >> del >> year;`?

Comment: I am sure I saw this question a day or two ago.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prompt for and receive a date "MM/DD/YYYY" using CIN, ignoring the "/" characters? (in C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483655/prompt-for-and-receive-a-date-mm-dd-yyyy-using-cin-ignoring-the-character)

Comment: @IlanKeshet No need to use `strtok()`, `getline()` by itself will suffice, as you can give it `'/'` as a delimiter to stop reading at.

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah... dumb me.