# How to read a date with cin

Tags: c++, cin

If user enters date in `mm / dd / yyyy` format, how do I retrieve it correctly?

`std::cin >> month >> day >> year;` does not work.

Comment: Take a look at  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/local_t/from_stream Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24483655/prompt-for-and-receive-a-date-mm-dd-yyyy-using-cin-ignoring-the-character

Comment: @doug that looks like a good enough link to mark this as a dupe.  Good searching!

Comment: `char slash1, slash2; if (!(cin >> month >> slash1 >> day >> slash2 >> year) || slash1 != '/' || slash2 != '/') throw "oopsies";`

Comment: @HowardHinnant And thanks for your contribution to the date/time in c++20. Looking forward to using it.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`std::get_time()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time), eg:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

std::tm tmb;
std::cin >> std::get_time(&tmb, "%m/%d/%Y");

int month = tmb.tm_mon + 1;
int day = tmb.tm_mday;
int year = tmb.tm_year + 1900;
```

Comment: Very convenient, I had not used that before. The documentation for `%d` or `%m` (or for `%D` for that matter) states *"leading zeroes permitted but not required"*. However, on testing, the stream state is set to fail if the leading zeros are not entered and the corresponding date values are corrupted (even initializing `std::tm tmb{};`) Am I missing something on the leading zeros?  Tested on gcc 7.4.1 and 11.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can define these variables to save the values:

```cpp
int month;
int day;
int year;
char dummy;
```

Then you have two options:

1. Capture all the values assuming the data will be typed in this format *month/day/year*, the "/" will be saved in the variable called *dummy* and the information for the date on the *ints*:

```cpp
cin >> month >> dummy >> day >> dummy >> year;
```

2. Or you can capture the data using the same format *month/day/year*, and validate that each int is separated by a "/" (*for this case is not required to define a char variable*):

```cpp
 cin >> month;
 if (cin.get() != '/')
 {
     cout << "Follow the format month/day/year" << endl;
     return 1;
 }
 cin >> day; 
 if (cin.get() != '/')
 {
     cout << "Follow the format month/day/year" << endl;
     return 1;
 }
 cin >> year;
```